# How To Update a GitHub Repository?

Tags: git, github, fedora

I am new at using GitHub, and am still getting used to all the command-line magic I need to do to upload my project.

But what I cannot figure out is how to update my GitHub repository. I keep looking around, and all I find is other questions about "Updating GitHub forked repository?", or other questions that are close to what I want, but not exact.

I already have content in my GitHub repository, and am trying to do the following from command-line git:

```
cd /home/robertclaytonreed/Projects/FOLDER/CONTENT
git init
cd ../
git add CONTENT/
git commit -m 'Updated Version'
git remote add origin https://github.com/USERNAME/FOLDER.git
git push origin master
```

Here I enter my username and password, and Git replies with:

```
fatal: remote origin already exists
```

If it's needed, I'm using Fedora 18 on a Compaq Netbook.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: git remote -v should list the remotes so you can see what origin is set to

Comment: Try just doing `git push`. The error means that you already have a remote (Github) set, so you don't need the `remote add` line. If you cloned your repo from github it will already have its remote set.

Comment: Wait -- Do you intentionally call `git init` inside a sub directory of what I assume is already a git repository? Or is this part of the guessing?

Answer (score 0):

To clone an exisiting repo to your folder just do git clone:

```
cd /DIRECTORY_WHERE_CREATE_REPO/
git clone https://github.com/REPOSITORY_URL
```